Не получается в телеграм боте одновременно делать рассылку и отвечать на сообщения
Делаю пирограм бота, который:

делает ежедневную рассылку пользователям
отвечает на их сообщения

Делаю через пирограмм. Бот пишет от имени обычного тг юзера. Ежедневную рассылку делаю через
def run_start():
    asyncio.run(start())

schedule.every().day.at("21:21").do(run_start)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    введите сюда код

отвечаю пользователям через
@app.on_message(filters.private)
async def handle_message(client, message)

И вот проблема в том, что если я запускаю бота через шедуль, то метод handle_message не срабатывает. Однако если я запущу бота без шедуля, просто через app.run(start()), то метод вызывается
Как я могу распараллелить эти процессы?
я думал в две разные программы разнести рассылку и ответы на сообщения, но две сессии не может быть запущено с одной тг учетки

Попробуйте сделать через loop (поддерживает асинхронность), а не shedule (он не работает с асинхронностью)
